# How to adjust select option text?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have to reduce the height of the form fields it works fine on all the fields except the select option which gets ruined. 
It seems to be taking top padding so apart from the size if there is a way to move the option text upwards that would be a good solution.
https://jsfiddle.net/04uv38e7/

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style type="text/css">
      .row.form {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
      }
      .form-control {
       height: 28px;
      }
      h5 {
        color: black;
      }
    </style>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="form-wrap"> 
<div class="container-outer">
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
          <h5>Book A Trip</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
    <form>
      <div class="row form">
      <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-2 form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First name">
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-2 form-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name">
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-2 form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-2 form-group">
        <select class="form-control input-sm">
          <option>Select property type</option>
          <option>Villa</option>
          <option>Plot</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="btndiv col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2">
        <button class="btn">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    </form>    
  </div> <!-- container end -->
</div> <!-- outer container end -->
</div> <!-- wrapper -->
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `style="padding:0 7px 3px"` to `<select>` tag.

as you can see:

```html
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style type="text/css">
      .row.form {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
      }
      .form-control {
       height: 28px;
      }
      h5 {
        color: black;
      }
    </style>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="form-wrap"> 
<div class="container-outer">
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
          <h5>Book A Trip</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
    <form>
      <div class="row form">
      <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-2 form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First name">
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-2 form-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name">
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-2 form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-2 form-group">
        <select class="form-control input-sm" style="padding:0 7px 3px">
          <option >Select property type</option>
          <option>Villa</option>
          <option>Plot</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="btndiv col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2">
        <button class="btn">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    </form>    
  </div> <!-- container end -->
</div> <!-- outer container end -->
</div> <!-- wrapper -->
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```